# creating a general utility class in c++

Tags: c++

Since i use arrays most of the time , i am in idea of creating a class which performs insertion,deletion,searching and other operations using vectors.

```
arrOperation obj = new arrOperation(); 
obj.insert(arr,val);
```

as shown above, i am creating an object for the general utility class in which i have written the code for insertion,deletion and other operations. My question is , Whether it is good to write such a class and use the functions in it or it is good to have the insertion, deletion functions in the same class itself? and i need some ideas about the areas where i can make some code and can be reused whenever i am in need of it

Comment: No offense intended, but I really can’t see the point of that class. What more does it bring? For instance, how is `obj.insert(vec,val)` better than `vec.push_back(val)`?

Comment: i ve updated the code, hope it means something now

Comment: Given that your example code contains `new` completely gratuitously, I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that you've recently come in from a very different programming background, and thus I'd say "no, don't do anything like that". Instead, get used to the C++ idioms which should already cover your needs.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like what you want is the `std::vector` class. Appending would be push_back(val), `insert` is `insert`, and `remove` is `erase`.

Comment: yes, sorry. i really messed up. i was thinking about arrays and i posted vectors.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "vector" in your question it seems you are talking of a built-in array. If that's the case, please have a look at `std::vector<T>` which pretty much seems to do what you are looking for.

If you are talking about packaging some operations which are not available in `std::vector<T>`, you should probably consider making them "algorithms" which are applicable to a suitable sequence. For example, `std::vector<T>` doesn't have a method for sorting its elements but there is an algorithm, `std::sort()`, which can sort any random access sequence, e.g., a `std::vector<T>` (as long as there is a strict weak order defined for the type `T`, of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to program in Java, use Java.
Creating objects on the heap to provide functions to other objects is not what C++ is meant for.

You can use free functions, to write frequent operations on existing types.

And you can use standard library classes if you need dynamic memory.

a class that provides operations is a need only for languages that don't allow free functions to exist.

Comment: This answer ought to mention namespaces and static member functions?

Comment: yes... but they don't add "functionality": just "organization". Namespaced functions as well as static members plays like free functions: they don't bind any object (and don't see any `this` in their body). My point is to make evident that function can exist independently of a "carrier object"